# Dc motor advice

Tags: motor, dc

Everyone. I need to build my own fan but I need dc motor advice.
I'm working on a blower fan, and I need to get about 5000 - 4000 rpm so I bought a car fan,it is turning 2700 rpm and air flow isn't enough for me. So now I decided to buy a new dc motor to build for my requirement able to get enough air flow. So, efficient is so important for this reason can I use brushless motor for build radial fan. And what is your advice ( website or company or size of motors and etc)

The reason why I ask that question is the fan I bought size is really big but brushless motor size mostly too small. Could it be any reason the factory uses big dc motor in blower fan? Why they not used RS series dc motor (rs55,775 etc).  The factory motor size is 60mm radius diameter and length is 75,5mm and brushed 12v, 2700 rpm, draws 5 amper with blades.

Comment: The power required to drive a propellor or fan varies as the cube of the speed. So to get a 1.5x speed increase (2700 to 4050 rpm) requires 1.5^3 = 3.375x the power ... call it 3.5x the power. As your current fan takes 60W you're looking for a motor taht can provide at least 210W at more than 4050 rpm. The rest is shopping and off topic.

Comment: @Brian Drummond So, you said whatever I do , I need 3 times more energy. They say brushless motor is very efficient ?

Comment: Brushed or brushless doesn't matter. Brushed is simpler though.

Comment: And airflow will depend on the restrictions to flow in your setup. Fans will probably be rated for free air delivery. Imagine the fan in a great big baffle with no obstructions on the inlet side and none on the outlet. If your situation is not like this then you will need an even more powerful fan.